# Tabular data iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to display tabular data in a view in an iphone application.

The data i want to show is 10 columns wide and about 8 rows. The columns are mostly integers except for one column which will be a name. These 10 columns won't fit on the screen so i would include a scrolling view to allow users to scroll the table in a vertical direction to be able to view each column. But i can't figure out how to show multiple columns of data.

I've looked into [Shinobigrids](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobigrids) but this solution is quite expensive. Are there any other grids available which are open-source or are there any tutorials on how to build these yourself?

Comment: is 10 columns and 8 rows fixed or will change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a single table view with custom cells, and each cell to have multiple columns, or add multiple tables to a `UIScrollView` (I'd prefer this one) and you can scroll each column individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try using collectionView it displays a collection of cells through which users can scroll. Each cell in a collection view is a UICollectionViewCell object. Hope this helps you..;)